# Javascript oddness with array of objects and indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexof

Not quite grasping what's going on here. Given the array (arr):

```
[
    {
        "first_name": "Dan",
        "last_name": "Woodson",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Jen",
        "last_name": "Woodson",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Yoshi",
        "last_name": "Woodson",
        "id": 3
    }
]
```

And the object (obj):

```
{
    "first_name": "Yoshi",
    "last_name": "Woodson",
    "id": 3
}
```

Why would `arr.indexOf(obj)` return `-1` (especially since I retrieved the object from the array using it's 'id' parameter earlier in the function)?

Comment: What do you mean "Earlier in the function" ? You need to show us the code that you wrote which fails, not just some JSON.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you're using, and/or put it on a fsFiddle?

Comment: This is because `({a:12}) === ({a:12})` is `false`.  Objects in JavaScript are equal if they are the same object (same reference), not just the same values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array.indexOf()` will only work on objects if the supplied object is *exactly the same object you put in*.

An exact *copy* is insufficient, it has to be the *exact same object*, i.e. there must be some object in the array such that:

```
arr[i] === obj
```

You need to show how you retrieved the object.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to see the retrieve function, but most likely you are not using the same reference. Because the following is true:

```
var a = {id: 3};
var b = [a];
b.indexOf(a); // 0
a.id = "not three";
b.indexOf(a); // still 0
```

However, the following will break:

```
var a = {id: 3};
var b = [{id: 3}];
b.indexOf(a); // -1 not the same object
```